# Generate custom CSV export from JSON data

Tags: php, silverstripe

In one of my ModelAdmin tabs, I have a column containing JSON-encoded data which I want to convert into a CSV table and export. Most of the questions I've seen were exporting rows of data directly from tables but how about extracting the data from one of the columns first before converting it to a CSV table for export.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you _haven't_ tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your _existing_ code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm not asking you or anyone to write the code for me, I'm just asking for ideas. Thanks to @KikoGarcia for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@KikoGarcia, thanks for the input. However, it would be simpler to do it like this. Also, when I tried your code, it copies the whole page to the exported CSV file. There must be an `exit();` included after `fclose();`.

After converting the JSON data to array, I had to loop through and create another array since there are nested data in it which I need for export. Once I got the final array, I call this function i.e.  `$this->arrayToCSVExport($finalArr);`

```
public function arrayToCSVExport($array, $filename = "backup.csv") {
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');
$bookdata = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($bookdata, array(
      'Customer Type',
      'Company Name',
      'Contact First Name',
      'Contact Last Name',
      'Contact Phone',
      'Contact Mobile',
      'Contact Email',
      'Contact Address',
      'Course Name',
      'Event ID',
      'Student First Name',
      'Student Last Name',
      'Student Phone',
      'Student Mobile',
      'Student Email',
      'Student Address',
      'Purchase Order'
));
foreach ($array as $user) {
   fputcsv($bookdata, $user);
}
fclose($bookdata);
exit();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As you're using PHP and want to output as CSV, the first thing you should do is convert that JSON to Array. Then you can use some PHP functions to prompt the result as CSV. Let's code:

```
$arr = json_decode($jsonInput, true);
if(empty($arr)) {
     die("INVALID JSON");
}
$filename = "your-filename.csv";
$now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
header("Expires: $now GMT");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");  
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
$df = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputs($df, $bom = ( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));
fputcsv($df, array_keys(reset($arr)), ';');
foreach($arr as $row) {
    fputcsv($df, $row, ';');
}
fclose($df);
```